# Export large data to excel into multiple sheets using C#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, export

I need to export datatable of 6'00'000+ records into excel. **I tried with the code as below,** **but I am getting the `OutOfMemory exception`**. Now I thought to export all these records into multiple sheets instead of single sheet to overcome with this error.

Here is the my code to export data into excel.

```
            private void ExportDataToExcel(DataTable Tbl)
             {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PeriodicJobEvents.xls");

                GridView excel = new GridView();
                excel.DataSource = Tbl;
                excel.DataBind();
                excel.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output));

                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

**Kindly help me understand how to export 6'00'000+ records into multiple sheets.**

Comment: I see a certain disconnection between your code and your question. Do you want to render a GridView control with the data or export and save the DataTable to an Excel file? If the second try exporting it to CSV instead delimited by a semicolon. That will open normally in Excel. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665519/Writing-a-DataTable-to-a-CSV-file

Comment: second one is my question. I need to upload without for loos as it has many records, loop will take much time.